Does this translation of Pushkin follow the accepted principles of "perfect rhyme" in English verse?
I am trying to translate Pushkin. This is an excerpt from his "Tale about a dead princess and seven knights", which is itself a variation of the Grimm brothers' fairy tale "Snowwhite".

     As a dowry she received
     Just one mirror, it's believed;
     But this mirror was unique,
     For it had the gift to speak.
     With this mirror she would be
     Kind and cheerful, wild and free,
     With it playfully she'd chatter
     And would ask, no idle matter:
     "Mirror mine, oh please do say,
     Tell the truth to me today;
     As you did the day before,
     Tell me, tell me, I implore:
     Am I fairest in creation,
     Most rose-cheeked in every nation?"
     And the mirror would reply:
     "You're the fairest, none deny;
     You're the fairest, as you know,
     Every day, it's always so."
     Then the Queen would laugh with glee,
     Shrug her shoulders merrily,
     Wink her eyes in pure delight,
     Snap her fingers swift and bright,
     Twirl around with hands on hips,
     Joy upon her royal lips.

Original:

Ей в приданое дано
Было зеркальце одно;
Свойство зеркальце имело:
Говорить оно умело.
С ним одним она была
Добродушна, весела,
С ним приветливо шутила
И, красуясь, говорила:
«Свет мой, зеркальце! Скажи,
Да всю правду доложи:
Я ль на свете всех милее,
Всех румяней и белее?»
И ей зеркальце в ответ:
«Ты, конечно, спору нет;
Ты, царица, всех милее,
Всех румяней и белее».
И царица хохотать,
И плечами пожимать,
И подмигивать глазами,
И прищёлкивать перстами,
И вертеться подбочась,
Гордо в зеркальце глядясь.

https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Сказка_о_мёртвой_царевне_и_о_семи_богатырях_(Пушкин)

All the rhymes sound fine to me.

I always dislike questions that ask if forced poetry and bad lyrics are good. Except that these are good regardless of their match to the original.

@YosefBaskin I think, this translation is very close to the original. The differences are: in the original it is "a mirror", not "just one mirror", the mirror responds saying the inferencer is fair and rose-cheeked, and I've added 4 lines to underline the rite is daily, but these lines can be romoved without breaking anything:      As you did the day before,
Tell me, tell me, I implore: (...)      You're the fairest, as you know,
Every day, it's always so.

@YosefBaskin Also, in the original it uses two separate words for beautiful and white, but in English I decided to combine them into one, "fair".

The only problem is glee/merrily. In English, perfect rhyming requires everything from the final stressed vowel to be identical. And since merrily is stressed on the first syllable, its rhymes are things like verily and (depending on one’s dialect) scarily.
That said, there’s no objective standard by which your laugh with glee/merrily couplet could be judged so harshly as to rate it as a bad rhyme.

I also thought about this, but I inserted it into many speech generators and they all stress the final syllable in "merrily".

For instance, this https://luvvoice.com/ and this https://voicegenerator.io/ synthesizers...

Those many speech generators are not to be trusted. Merr-i-ly, Adverbs ending in -ly are never stressed on that final syllable.

What about the "around"? Does it have three syllables?


What around?



Posts should contain single questions.


In "Twirl around", in this poem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Try singing it to twinkle twinkle little star. The are two couplets with an extra syllable on the last note, but that is not really a problem for singers. When sung, merrily fits perfectly.

No, @Peter, at least not for perfect rhyme. If glee is not stressed in its line, then the final stressed syllable is laugh, so a perfect rhyme would have to end in -ith-gly.

@PaulTanenbaum Are we at cross purposes? I supposed that each line of music (7 notes with accents on 1,3,5 and 7) would be a single line of the verse, so there would be a single note for chatter and, in the next line, for matter. Likewise a single note for -ation and for nation. In my experience as a church organist congregations singing hymns do this sort of thing as a matter of course. This means that the 4th verse would have its first two lines ending in laugh with glee and merrily respectively.

@Peter, are you focusing on (perfect) rhyme or on meter? As an example, She is brave, most certainly / I have seen her climb a tree is not a perfect rhyme, whereas She can act, most certainly / One might say Jane Curtinly is. Or, if meter doesn’t matter, Richard Burtonly.

@PaulTanenbaum If you use the music to enforce the meter then the rhyme becomes perfect when you sing it.

We're at the rhyme/meter interface here. The -ly syllable of merrily has to be sustained for a longer duration than it would be sustained in speech, sustained as if it were being sung.  It's as if the line wants to be sung, or is breaking into song.

In normal speech -ly doesn't get any stress. But it's not uncommon for it to get secondary stress to fit the meter in poetry. "Shrug her shoulders merrily" is not bad meter.
